# A way to enter a website with different IP address each time

Tags: python, proxy

I am making a program to enter a website each time with a different IP address to accomplish a task. At first I used rotational proxies but they patched that. Anybody got any suggestions on what I can use? If I enter the website with only one IP they will block that. I need a different IP address each time. It should also work with Python.

Comment: what have you done before? what code do you tried already what is the input and so and so on? There are so many details missing in the question that is impossible to give you a reasonable answer and btw StackOverflow is not a "here is my problem to all the code I am to lazy to code it myself"

Comment: If you're getting blocked from websites on your IP i don't think it's the websites that are at fault

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a code writing service](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69798/is-stack-overflow-a-code-writing-service#:~:text=Stack%20Overflow%20is%20a%20question,expect%20to%20get%20an%20answer.), let alone one that will enable you to circumvent security features that someone else has put in place with likely good reason.

Comment: @gerdadiegandalfziege Hi, Thanks for your response. I tried using rotational proxies on my code and they recently stopped working. I am sorry but I cannot release the code. The proxy link was in a JSON file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a [CCC talk (german)](https://media.ccc.de/v/rc3-659299-bundesanzeiger_crawling#t=920) they suggested using aws spot instances as an alternative to rotating proxies. They are relatively cheap ([up to 90% discount](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/spot)) and can be started and stopped flexibly. The idea is getting a new machine for a new ip.
Other cloud providers have comparable offers. [Eg google cloud](https://cloud.google.com/spot-vms)